# Have userform span multiple Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, charts, excel-2013, userform

I have a userform that's used to copy chart formats from one chart to another.  There's a "Set To Selected" button to store the location of the selected chart, but this only works within the main Workbook.  If I select a chart in a different Workbook and then click the button, the original Workbook becomes the ActiveWorkbook again.

Here's a snippet from the code.

```
Private Sub btnSetToSelected_Click()
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  txtWorkbookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
  txtChartName = ActiveChart.Name
  Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
  MsgBox ("You do not have a chart selected.")
End Sub
```

Is it possible to have a userform span multiple Workbooks like this, or are userforms confined to the Workbooks in which they were originally opened?

Thanks,

Trekopep

Comment: Are you using Excel 2013 by any chance?

Comment: Indeed, I am.  Is this a version-specific problem?

Comment: Yes it is, due to the change from MDI to SDI. Have a read of Jan Karel's article here: http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/keepuserformontop.asp

Comment: Beautiful.  Works perfectly.  Feel free to post this as a solution.